# American flag vertical

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a vertical version of the American flag off an old one I made, but I'm  not sure what to do because it's been a while since I've done this.

Here's the code itself, it makes an American flag.  I'm trying to figure out how to make this image go vertical.

It doesn't matter what side the navy is on, just as long as the lines go down, I tried changing some numbers but it went all over the place.

```
import turtle
import time


screen = turtle.getscreen()

screen.bgcolor("white")


oogway = turtle.Turtle()

oogway.speed(10)
oogway.penup()

oogway.shape("turtle")


flag_height = 250
flag_width = 475


start_x = -237
start_y = 125


stripe_height = flag_height/13
stripe_width = flag_width


star_size = 10


def draw_fill_rectangle(x, y, height, width, color):
    oogway.goto(x,y)
    oogway.pendown()
    oogway.color(color)
    oogway.begin_fill()
    oogway.forward(height)
    oogway.forward(90)
    oogway.forward(width)
    oogway.right(90)
    oogway.forward(width)
    oogway.right(90)
    oogway.forward(height)
    oogway.right(90)
    oogway.end_fill()
    oogway.penup()

def draw_star(x,y,color,length) :
    oogway.goto(x,y)
    oogway.setheading(0)
    oogway.pendown()
    oogway.begin_fill()
    oogway.color(color)
    for turn in range(0,5) :
        oogway.forward(length)
        oogway.right(144)
        oogway.forward(length)
        oogway.right(144)
    oogway.end_fill()
    oogway.penup()



def draw_stripes():
    x = start_x
    y = start_y

    for stripe in range(0,6):
        for color in ["red", "white"]:
            draw_fill_rectangle(x, y, stripe_height, stripe_width, color)

            y = y - stripe_height            


    draw_fill_rectangle(x, y, stripe_height, stripe_width, 'red')
    y = y - stripe_height



def draw_square():
    square_height = 133
    square_width =  185
    draw_fill_rectangle(start_x, start_y, square_height, square_width, 'navy')


def draw_six_stars_rows():
    gap_between_stars = 30
    gap_between_lines = stripe_height + 6
    y = 112
    # create 5 rows of stars
    for row in range(0,5) :
        x = -222
        # create 6 stars in each row
        for star in range (0,6) :
            draw_star(x, y, 'white', star_size)
            x = x + gap_between_stars
        y = y - gap_between_lines


def draw_five_stars_rows():
    gap_between_stars = 30
    gap_between_lines = stripe_height + 6
    y = 100
    # create 4 rows of stars
    for row in range(0,4) :
        x = -206
        # create 5 stars in each row
        for star in range (0,5) :
            draw_star(x, y, 'white', star_size)
            x = x + gap_between_stars
        y = y - gap_between_lines

# start after 5 seconds.
time.sleep(5)
# draw 13 stripes
draw_stripes()
# draw squares to hold stars
draw_square()
# draw 30 stars, 6 * 5
draw_six_stars_rows()
# draw 20 stars, 5 * 4. total 50 stars representing 50 states of USA
draw_five_stars_rows()
# hide the cursor/turtle
oogway.hideturtle()
# keep holding the screen until closed manually
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we address the vertical flag issue, let's revisit your horizontal one.  Your code gives a false impression that it can size the flag as needed:

```
flag_height = 250
flag_width = 475
```

But there are too many embedded numbers to allow this to happen:

```
start_x = -237
start_y = 125
star_size = 10
square_height = 133
square_width =  185
gap_between_stars = 30
gap_between_lines = stripe_height + 6
y = 112
x = -222
y = 100
x = -206
```

So let's rewrite your code to draw a horizontal flag without all those embedded numbers:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States

FLAG_HOIST = 250
FLAG_FLY = FLAG_HOIST * 1.9

STRIPE_WIDTH = FLAG_HOIST/13

CANTON_HOIST = STRIPE_WIDTH * 7
CANTON_FLY = 2 * FLAG_FLY / 5

STAR_DIAMETER = 4 * STRIPE_WIDTH / 5

VERTICAL_STAR_GAP = -CANTON_HOIST/5
HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP = CANTON_FLY/6

START_X = -FLAG_FLY/2
START_Y = FLAG_HOIST/2

def draw_fill_rectangle(x, y, width, height, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_star(x, y, color, length):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(144)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()

def draw_stripes():
    y = START_Y

    for _ in range(6):
        for color in ['red', 'white']:
            draw_fill_rectangle(START_X, y, FLAG_FLY, STRIPE_WIDTH, color)

            y -= STRIPE_WIDTH

    draw_fill_rectangle(START_X, y, FLAG_FLY, STRIPE_WIDTH, 'red')

def draw_square():
    draw_fill_rectangle(START_X, START_Y, CANTON_FLY, CANTON_HOIST, 'navy')

def draw_six_stars_rows():
    y = START_Y + VERTICAL_STAR_GAP/2

    # create 5 rows of stars
    for _ in range(5):
        x = START_X + (HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP/2 - STAR_DIAMETER/2)
        # create 6 stars in each row
        for _ in range(6):
            draw_star(x, y, 'white', abs(STAR_DIAMETER))
            x += HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP
        y += VERTICAL_STAR_GAP

def draw_five_stars_rows():
    y = START_Y + VERTICAL_STAR_GAP

    # create 4 rows of stars
    for _ in range(4):
        x = START_X + (HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP - STAR_DIAMETER/2)
        # create 5 stars in each row
        for _ in range(5):
            draw_star(x, y, 'white', abs(STAR_DIAMETER))
            x += HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP
        y += VERTICAL_STAR_GAP

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.penup()

# draw 13 stripes
draw_stripes()
# draw squares to hold stars
draw_square()
# draw 30 stars, 6 * 5
draw_six_stars_rows()
# draw 20 stars, 5 * 4. total 50 stars representing 50 states of USA
draw_five_stars_rows()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Now that we've abstracted the code, turning the flag vertical is a matter of swapping the default heading of 0 degrees for 270 degrees, flipping the sign on a few of our contants and reversing x and y in our `goto()` calls:

```
13c13
< STAR_DIAMETER = 4 * STRIPE_WIDTH / 5
---
> STAR_DIAMETER = -4 * STRIPE_WIDTH / 5
16c16
< HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP = CANTON_FLY/6
---
> HORIZONTAL_STAR_GAP = -CANTON_FLY/6
18c18
< START_X = -FLAG_FLY/2
---
> START_X = FLAG_FLY/2
23c23
<   turtle.goto(x, y)
---
>   turtle.goto(y, x)
36,37c36,37
<   turtle.goto(x, y)
<   turtle.setheading(0)
---
>   turtle.goto(y, x)
>   turtle.setheading(270)
91c91
< turtle.setheading(0)
---
> turtle.setheading(270)
```

[image]